# Batch Script User input with spaces

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting

Im trying to have a script that needs the user to input a folders name, when a name with no spaces is written everything works fine, but everytime a folder name with spaces is written it doesnt this my code. Can someone help me fix that problem.

```
@echo off


if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Backup" mkdir C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Backup
set backupdir=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Backup
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y


:loop

echo Your current directory is
echo %cd%

echo.

echo These are the folders in your derectory.
dir /a:d /b

echo.

echo Type the name of a folder to move into that directory or back to move to the previous directory. 
echo Once you get to the directory you want type finish in order to backup that directory.

:user_input
set /p  userInput= Enter Directory Name or type finish to back the files : 
echo.

if %userInput% == back (
    cd ..
) else if not exist %userInput% (
    if not %userInput% == finish (
        echo This directory doesnt exist please try again.
        goto:user_input
    )
) else if "%userInput%" (
    cd %cd%\%userInput%
)

if %userInput% == finish (

    goto:backup_start
) else (
    goto:loop
)



:backup_start
%backupcmd% "%cd%" "%backupdir%"

echo Backup Complete
@pause
```

Comment: `else if "%userInput%" (` ? Think again.

Comment: why is this post tagged with `powershell`?

Comment: The elsi if "%userInput%" was the problem. Thank you everyone for taking time to help me.